# Create list with depth equal 2

Tags: r, list, subscript

I have a list with a depth equal 2. I would like to subscript that list as described in the following example:

```
my.list<-list(
  a=list(
    a1=1:10,
    a2=11:20),
  b=list(
    b1=21:30,
    b2=31:40),
  c=list(
    c1=41:50,
    c2=51:60)
)
# choose a specific item 
my.list[[2]][[2]][[3]]

# choose all first items from a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2
test<-list()
for(i in 1:3)
  for (j in 1:2)test[[i]][[j]]<-my.list[[i]][[j]][[1]]

test

Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

But this won't work since the list I created has no lists within it. What works is to do like this:

```
test<-list()
for(i in 1:3)
  for (j in 1:2)test[[i]]<-my.list[[i]][[j]][[1]]
```

and then

```
test<-list()
for(i in 1:3)
  for (j in 1:2)test[[i]][[j]]<-my.list[[i]][[j]][[1]]

test
```

gives:

```
[[1]]
[1]  1 11

[[2]]
[1] 21 31

[[3]]
[1] 41 51
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following code solve your problem?

```
lapply(my.list, sapply, head, 1)
```

gives you the first element of each vector for each entry in `my.list`:

```
$a
a1 a2 
 1 11 

$b
b1 b2 
21 31 

$c
c1 c2 
41 51
```

Comment: yes I think this will help me somehow. Still i was wondering if there is not anythink build-in when creating new lists itself.

Comment: I think `lapply` is the built-in function that you are looking for: It iterates over a list, creates a new list and returns it. See `?lapply`

Comment: From your edit I see that the result you want is a list with three entries each containing a vector. Since `lapply` returns a list, you can use the `sapply` wrapper which returns a vector. I will edit the answer.